# Is there a better way to find the most popular title in a 'self-linked' table of user posts?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have this (simplified for space) table schema with user posts and related comments:

```
create table 
 tbl_post (
   id       integer  primary key,
   title    text     not null,
   content  text     not null,
   post_id  integer  null
 );
```

where `tbl_post.post_id` is an *(int)* comment id associated with given `tbl_post.id`,
or `null` if `tbl_post.id` row is main, authored title (namely not a comment).
I'm using this [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) query to figure out the most popular title in posts table (criteria is how many comments relates to it...):

```
select
  title
from
  tbl_post
where
  id = (
    select 
      post_id 
    from (
      select
        post_id, count(post_id) as tot
      from
        tbl_post
      where
        ifnull(post_id, '') != ''
      group by
        post_id
      order by
        tot desc
      limit 1
    )
  );
```

which looks quite bulky to me having those two nested `select` statements. I would like to make the query simpler (shorter, potentialy faster) somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a self-join?

```
SELECT p.Id p.title, p.content, COUNT(c.Id) AS nbOfComments
FROM tbl_post p
LEFT JOIN tbl_post c ON p.Id = c.post_id
WHERE p.post_id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.Id, p.title, p.content
```

Comment: nice trick with `LEFT JOIN` + `p.post_id IS NULL`. If I would to read only single piece of text data, title in this case, not complete result set, I have to pull the `title` field from sorted set, which means expanding the query with aditional 'sub-selects', right?

Comment: I didn't get your question. You can add `ORDER BY` here. And it already returns not just the `Id`, but also `Title` and `Content` for the posts. If you'd like to get the comments content too, you need additional queries.

Comment: nevermind, should have put it more clearly... like the answer, it just looks `.post_id = null` rows, where mine was doing kind of opposite I guess.